# table in local email client from web

Tags: javascript, web-applications, outlook

I have an html table in my web page.  The client has requested that I provide a link on the page which opens a new email message from the local mail client that has the table from the web page embedded in the body.  I can get the new message up with the mailto: link but I have been unable to figure a viable way to populate the table into that new message.

For background most of the users are using Firefox on Windows 7 with their local mail client being Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to inform you that this will be impossible. According to [rfc2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368) which defines the behaviour of the mailto uri scheme, the body hname defines the first text/plain portion of the mail and there is no way to define the text/html portion of the email.

The closest you would be able to get is to have a textbased representation of a table, but that (of course) won't look too well. Alternatively you could consider making an outlook **only** solution by generating an outlook template (.oft) which I believe will open a new compose email dialog when opened, but I would strongly discourage this solution.

In this case I don't know what the exact reason is that there is a requirement for the link to open the users mail client, but in general the right way to go would be to make a custom form on your website which is handled server side (and server side you of course can define the exact behaviour and content of the email).